# Apache & Rstudio Shiny App Redirect/Proxy

Tags: apache, shiny, shiny-server

I have found many suggestions around the net on this, but nothing that matches my exact issue. I have a webserver setup, that I have had our networking guys give me a DNS name for. Let's call it `analytics.mycompany.com`. This runs on port 80 and I have not issues.

A few months back I created an RStudio Shiny app that, by default, runs on port 3838. Therefore, I get to this via `http://analytics.mycompany.com:3838/dashboard/`. Which is all good and fine, but leadership has asked for an easier URL. I had my DNS guys give me an alias to the `analytics.mycompany.com` as `dashboard.mycompany.com`. Which, by default just points to the same port 80 website.

Now, I figure with a little apache/virtualhost/rewriterules/proxy I can tell apache to handle anything it receives from the `dashboard.mycompany.com` to just display the dashboard at `http://analytics.mycompany.com:3838/dashboard/`. After playing with this, I can get a URL like `http://analytics.mycompany.com/dashboard/` to forward to the correct :3838 port and URL, but what I really want is for someone to be able to just enter `http://dashboard.mycompany.com` and just have the shiny dashboard appear. I know in DNS you cannot make aliases to ports, so that is out. I was hoping apache could handle this in some way, by saying, "ok, I have this URL on port 80 and I'm going to just display the content of this other site at port 3838."

I'm not sure if this is possible, but it is what I'd like. Right now my httpd.conf file for the virtual host at port 80 is as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@mycompany.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^HEAD
   RewriteRule ^/dashboard(.*) /foo/index.html
   Redirect /dashboard http://analytics.mycompany.com:3838/dashboard
   ProxyPass /dashboard/ http://analytics.mycompany.com:3838/dashboard
   ProxyPassReverse /dashboard http://analytics.mycompany.com:3838/dashboard
</VirtualHost>
```

This was based on an example I found and is as close as I've come. I am thinking that I need some sort of virtual host for the new alias that might look like:

```
<VirtualHost dashboard.mycompany.com:80>
   .....
</VirtualHost>
```

However, all the examples I find of VirtualHost is either *:80 or some IP addres like 192.168.0.1:80 or the like. If anyone has a suggestion or a way I can server this up at a simple URL, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have found part of my answer. Based on another posting I had to modify the SELinux on RHEL with the following:  /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1 Once that was done, I can now enter http://analytics.mycompany.com/dashboard and it shows up without the :3838. Now all I need is to somehow make the "dashboard.mycompany.com" display the content at "http://analytics.mycompany.com/dashboard". Any further help on this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring this to a close, this was a two part process:

1. I had to disable SELinux as it was interfering.
2. I created a VirtualHost entry as specified above (basically a port redirect)
3. Since we use a primary DNS, I had to have my network folks add an entry to InfoBlox for the domain.

After that, everything was working as expected. :)